# Transpose plots on a graphics device R

Tags: r, graphics

```
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
plot(density(rnorm(100)))
plot(density(rexp(100)))
plot(density(rnorm(100)))
plot(density(rexp(100)))
plot(density(rnorm(100)))
plot(density(rexp(100)))
```

This gives me a 3x2 array of 6 plots.  Can I transpose this array without redoing my code?  (The original code that produced the plots is quite a bit more complicated than the above :) -- I am trying to beamer-ize something made for a latex A4 doc.)

Comment: I think the answer is no. Probably easier to just post-process it (cut up the resulting image in something like GIMP and then reassemble in whatever order you need).

Comment: If you just want something that has an appropriate aspect ratio for beamer, why not just change the first line to: par(mfrow=c(2,3))

Comment: ^Because that'll change the order they appear in.

Comment: No. Base graphics in R uses an "indelible ink" model. I wouldn't expect it to be particularly object oriented if you tried to work on it with GIMP or ImageMagick, either.

Answer (score 3):

Use `layout` instead of `par(mfrow=...)` for more flexible panelling.

The `layout` equivalent to your 3x2 panel `par` call is

```
layout(matrix(1:6, nrow=3, byrow=TRUE))
plot(...)
plot(...)
plot(...)
...
```

Change it to the following to transpose the array without having to change the `plot` calls

```
layout(matrix(1:6, 2))
plot(...)
plot(...)
plot(...)
...
```